# How to save a resized image in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I try to save both, an original and a resized image and can't understand on what step Django will understand from **which field** it will take the image to resize and then save.

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django_resized import ResizedImageField

class Post(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to ='uploads/posts/large/')
    thumbnail_small = ResizedImageField(size=[100, 100], upload_to='uploads/posts/small/')
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['thumbnail','thumbnail_small']
```

**Html:**

```
<form method = "POST" action = "{% url 'adminpanel' %}" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type = "file" id = "file" name = "thumbnail" accept = "image/png, image/jpeg">
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn" name = "apost">Add Post</button>
</form>
```

So, the question is, where will Django understand that it has to save image directly from the `<input name = "thumbnail">` directly to `thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to ='uploads/posts/large/')` and also to `thumbnail_small = ResizedImageField(size=[100, 100], upload_to='uploads/posts/small/')`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `save()` method for `PostForm` which inherits from `forms.ModelForm`, and then save the `cleaned_data()` separately for each field, `thumbnail` and `thumbnail_small`.

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['thumbnail']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        post = super().save(commit=False)

        image = self.cleaned_data['thumbnail']
        # Saves the image as is
        post.thumbnail = image
        # Saves the image resized, because the field does it automatically...
        post.thumbnail_small = image  

        if commit:
           post.save()

        return post
```

This `save()` method would run when `is_valid()` is `True`.